# VueJS: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined when Reload

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a page like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="row flex">
    {{posts.id}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
      let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/feeds/' + route.params.id + '/')
      return {
        posts: data
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I click link with hot reload (router-link), it display well. But when I reload this window, it appear in 1 seconds and disappear then.

Video: http://g.recordit.co/ht0a0K2X81.gif

Error Log:
[image: Error Log SSR]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a property to your data i.e `dataLoaded: false`. When your ajax request has finished, set `this.dataLoaded = true`. On your template add `v-if="dataLoaded`. This will mean the template data won't render until you're ready.

You could also do `v-if="posts"` as another way but I generally have a consistent `dataLoaded` prop available to do this.

Edit: I just looked at your example again and doing something like this would work:

```
<template>
  <div class="row flex" v-if="posts">
    {{posts.id}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    data () {
        return {
            posts: null
        }
    }
    methods:{ 
        loadPosts () {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/feeds/' + this.$route.params.id + '/')
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.loadPosts().then(({data}) => {
            this.posts = data
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've removed the `async` and just setting posts when the `axios` request returns it's promise. Then on the template, it's only showing `posts` is valid.

**Edit**

You can also use your original code and just add `v-if="posts"` to the div you have in your template.

Comment: See my edit, I've changed `route.params.id` to `this.$route.params.id` within the axios request.

Comment: This work: Change in create(): this.loadPosts().then((data) into this.loadPosts().then(({data}). It works.

Comment: Ah, good. Wasn't sure of the data structure but it was here for an example :) Glad it's working.

Comment: But do you have any better solution?

Comment: Not really, you only want to show the page when the data is loaded so this is the best approach. It's better than `await` as well because it means there's no blocking happening. I've used this method with great success over my app.

Comment: Thank you @webnoob very much!

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.

Comment: Sorry @webnoob. I get problem with SSR.. When I viewsource, it can't be rendered. Could you type solution: dataLoaded: false you said?

Comment: See my edit. Just add the check to the template using your original code and it should work. It'll only show the template when `posts` have been populated.

Comment: When I view source by Ctrl+U, it's just render: <div class="row flex"><!----></div>
P/S: I use NuxtJS with Vue Router

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just nothing showing? The code above *will* work if data is returned, I'd suggest further debugging is required.

Comment: Nothing Showing. It display well but SSR no thing. So when view source, it just be <div class="row flex"><!----></div> instead <div class="row flex">This is data posts</div>

Comment: Have you debugged the data coming back from the axios request? There's not much I can do to help. If Posts has data, the template will show. If it doesn't it won't. Debug the posts values.

Comment: Data coming back successful. The problem is it'snot rendered HTML, bro. You can take a look my file: https://github.com/feedgit/FeedTrue/blob/master/frontend/pages/f/_id.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159077/discussion-between-webnoob-and-feed-git).